# Reading SMS in android when SMS_RECEIVED action is captured by a BroadCastReceiver

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to set the body of SMS to EditText when I receive it.
I'm using BroadcastReceiver to capture the action SMS_RECEIVED and registering it using **registerReceiver()** method.

**Problem is**
When I receive sms nothing happens and EditText is not updated.

**What I tried for debugging**

I tried to set the EditText without BroadcastReceiver in onCreate() method only and it is updated with the text msg that is already received by the particular number.

```
public class CardActivity extends Activity {

EditText txtCardId;
final String SMS_URI_INBOX = "content://sms/inbox";
IntentFilter filter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.card);
    btnProceed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnProceed);
    txtCardId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCardId);
    filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver,filter);

    });
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            context = getApplicationContext();
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(SMS_URI_INBOX);
            String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };
            Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, "address='+919016832405'", null, "date desc");
            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                int index_Body = cur.getColumnIndex("body");
                String strbody;
                do {
                    strbody = cur.getString(index_Body);
                } while (cur.moveToNext());
                txtCardId.setText(strbody);

                if (!cur.isClosed()) {
                    cur.close();
                    cur = null;
                }
            } else {
                txtCardId.setText("nothing");
            } // end if
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex) {
            Log.d("SQLiteException", ex.getMessage());
        }
    }};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I found where I was mistaken**

I was using READ_SMS permission in menifest rather I need to use RECEIVE_SMS.
It worked.